# Change Spring MVC Security Directing to Login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to use Spring's security package. By default, when directed to the root URL the security controller takes over and presents the login.html page.

What I'd like is a nice landing page with a 'login' option that will display login.html.

How can I change this behavior. I'm very new to Spring.

My intercepts are configured as:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/assets/css/**" access="isAnonymous()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/assets/js/**" access="isAnonymous()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/assets/img/**" access="isAnonymous()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/header.html" access="isAnonymous() or hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome.html" access="isAnonymous() or hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="isAnonymous()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginFailed.html" access="isAnonymous()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/403.html" access="isAnonymous()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login.html" authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed.html"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout.html"/>
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403.html"/>
</http>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/jpaContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pdfs/**</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/images/**</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Have you set up intercept-url in a security-context configuration file?

Comment: Yes, I added my configuration to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Change `isAnonymous()` to `permitAll` - otherwise you can get some odd results once logged in.

In particular remember to leave the root of the web application accessible - that's probably why you are getting a redirect to the login page immediately.

e.g.
`<intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />`

Oh, and change this `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>` to

`<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />`

This makes sure that everything is secured by default and you then have to explicitly give permission, either by permitAll, hasRole, or isAuthenticated().  Otherwise a logged-in user has access to EVERYTHING that you haven't manually secured, which can be an obvious security risk.

Once the root and login page are set to `permitAll` you are then free to set your own login page, which the users can choose to login, rather than being immediately forced to do so as is the case presently.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I made those changes, but even with a manual:

@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET),

the login page is still presented.

Comment: You don't really need the `method=RequestMethod.GET` for that.  Can you also post your web.xml please?  Just to check the mappings correspond to urls that are not secured.

Comment: Absolutely! I added it to my original post.

Comment: Try this:  remove all the `<servlet-mapping>` entries and just have the one that has this:

  `<servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>`

Comment: Sadly, no. The application still goes straight to the login.html.

Comment: Hmmm..  is the security-context file definitely being loaded?  See the log, or watch at start-up.  Also, try removing the `<http auto-config='true'>` bit from your context file.

Comment: Yeah, everything has been loading correctly. I can log in successfully, and navigate around as needed. I guess I'll just have to keep playing with it. I truly appreciate the help.

Comment: Okay, best of luck  did you try removing the `auto-config='true'` entry?

Comment: Yes, sir. It still directed me straight to the login page.